# Symmetric difference of two sets in which one of them is union of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I wanna prove that:
$(A \cup B ) \Delta C = (A \Delta C) \cup (B-A)$
Another Problem is to  prove $(A \Delta B) \cup C = (A \cup C) \Delta (B-C)$
I want to prove these without venn diagrams...

Comment: well, one way to go about it would be to show that these sets are subsets of each other; i.e. take an element of the set on the left side and show that it has to be a member of the set on the right side, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You could prove two inclusions.

E.g. suppose $x \in (A \cup B) \Delta C$. 
Case 1: $x \in (A \cup B)$, but $x \notin C$. Then sub-case a: $ x \in A$. But then $x \in A - C \subset A \Delta C$, so $x$ is in the right hand side. Sub-case b: $x \notin A$, but then $x \in B$. But then $x \in B - A$, so also in the right side. This covers case 1.

Case 2: $x \in C$ but $x \notin A \cup B$. But then in particular, $x \in C - A \subset A \Delta C$, and so again in the right hand side.

Now try the reverse implication, and the other identity similarly.